# Localizing ios App

Tags: ios, localization

I have a working ios app in my hand. My company wants me to provide a "Translate" `button` in the app that would make it Arabic. Can I do this with `iOS Localisation`? The app is live in app store and I have to start with Localisation work now

Comment: you can't do like this, localization works automatically with respect to ios language settings. you can't have a translate button with ios localization feature, for this you have write your own logic but its possible.

Comment: Try this.. http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to localization strings in specific language, but in this case you need to implement your own function instead of `NSLocalizedString`. Here is an example:

```
NSString *Localized(NSString *key) {
static NSBundle *localizationBundle = nil;

static dispatch_once_t onceToken1;
dispatch_once(&onceToken1, ^
              {
                  NSString *languageCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode]; //The language code you need
                  localizationBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:languageCode ofType:@"lproj"]];
              });


NSString *string = [localizationBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:nil table:nil];
return string; }
```

Just reload `localizationBundle` every time user switches language by translate button